# Hiding the X axis of the Shield UI Chart

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I am trying to hide the X axis of the Shield UI Chart. The chart's type is bar. I tried to use enabled:

```
            axisX:
                {
                    enabled:false,
                },
```

but it doesn't work. I than tried to set the line's thickness to 0, but this is not working either. The line retains a minimum thickness. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ot the current version  Shield UI Chart, depending on the chart type, of course, the X axis cannot be hidden by setting a specified property. However the effect of invisibility can be achieved by setting the axis color to match the plot's color. Or to white in the most cases.

Comment: Yes. Quite simple actually. Not that I need to hide the X axis all the time. However comes in handy when needed.